# maven-jarsigner-plugin Enter Passphrase for keystore

Tags: maven-plugin

I am using maven-jarsigner-plugin to sign my applet jar. When i run "maven clean install" my build fails and gives following error.

```
                [DEBUG] 'cmd.exe /X /C ""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_33\jre\..\bin\jarsigner.exe" -keystore mykeystore -keypass '*****' C:\myproject\target\myapplet-1.0.0.jar applet"'
                [INFO] jarsigner: you must enter key password
                [WARNING] Enter Passphrase for keystore:
```

following is my maven configuration.

```
            <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jarsigner-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>sign</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>sign</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>         
                <keystore>mykeystore</keystore>
                <alias>myapplet</alias>
                <keypass>mykeypass</keypass>                    
            </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

I can see it prompts for password.

please let me know what i have missed in this configuration

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing

```
<storepass>mystorepass</storepass>
```

in

```
<configuration>         
     <keystore>mykeystore</keystore>
     <alias>myapplet</alias>
     <keypass>mykeypass</keypass>
     <storepass>mystorepass</storepass>                     
</configuration>
```

?